# Python 3 + Tkinter: Special case with entry.delete()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

As you see in the title, I think this is very special case.

In Tkinter, the delete method for Entry widget is:

```
Entry.delete(first, end)
```

with “Entry” being the name.

However, I recently found a code with multiple entries created inside a loop. In every iteration, the same variable is overwritten to create new Entry.

So I want to create a Button that ‘refresh’ the entry field once clicked and the problem is that the previous entries syntactically do not exist anymore!!

Any idea to solve this? I appreciate a lot!

Comment: Add each Entry to a list as it's created, loop over that list whenever you need to do something to all of them?

Comment: Any idea how to solve it? Sure: just keep a reference to every entry. This isn't a special case, it's how python objects work. If you throw away a reference to an object, you can no longer call methods on the object.

Comment: `with “Entry” being the name`. Fist let me say that naming your `Entry()` field Entry is really a bad idea. Never name something exactly like the method/function name. Second the simple solution is to save all entry fields in a list and just reference the list index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple example to show how when creating Entry fields in a loop (and probably any other widget in a loop) you should handle saving reference to this Entry field.

We create a list to store Entry object.

In our loop we append this list with the object directly.

Then we can just call on the list index to work with said object.

Update to reflect clearing the entry fields.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

entry_list = []

for i in range(10):
    entry_list.append(tk.Entry(root))
    entry_list[i].pack()

def refres_fields():
    for entry in entry_list:
        entry.delete(0, "end")

tk.Button(root, text="Clear Entry Fields", command=refres_fields).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. But first of all let me say that its normal in this case that you can't reach the previous Widgets. If your code looks somewhat like that:

```
for index in range(10):
    entry=Entry(root,cnf=your_config)
    entry.pack()
```

then its pretty much the same as:

```
entry=Entry(root,cnf=your_config)
entry.pack()

entry=Entry(root,cnf=your_config)
entry.pack()

entry=Entry(root,cnf=your_config)
entry.pack()

entry=Entry(root,cnf=your_config)
entry.pack()

entry=Entry(root,cnf=your_config)
entry.pack()

entry=Entry(root,cnf=your_config)
entry.pack()

entry=Entry(root,cnf=your_config)
entry.pack()

entry=Entry(root,cnf=your_config)
entry.pack()

entry=Entry(root,cnf=your_config)
entry.pack()

entry=Entry(root,cnf=your_config)
entry.pack()
```

so every time a new Entry widget gets assigned to 'entry' and just overrides the old meaning of 'entry'. But even thought you don't have access to the 'old Entrys' over 'entry' anymore, they are still saved.

Just as much for your understanding of the problem. Now to the solutions:
There are two solutions I that are pretty simple and work quite well.
The first one is that you, as jasonharper already mentioned, add them to an list as follows:

```
entrys=[]
for index in range(10):
    entry=Entry(root,cnf=your_config)
    entry.pack()
    entrys.append(entry)
```

or if you like it shorter (like I do):

```
entrys=[]
for index in range(10):
    entrys.append(Entry(root,cnf=your_config))
    entrys[index].pack()
```

Then you can iterate trough the list and access to every single Entry.

The other way is a bit more complex. It uses the exec(...) and the eval(...) command.
With exec you can execute code given as string and with eval you get the evaluation of a string.
Then your program would look somewhat like that:

```
for index in range(10):
    exec('entry%i=Entry(root,cnf=your_config)' % (index))
    eval('entry%i' % (index)).pack()
```

If you use the second solution you will have a separate variable for every Entry widget but you also may struggle with the strings at some points. (i.e.: You can't assign something to an evaluation, so: `eval('var')=1` wont work.)

Comment: If you are adding this to a list you do not need to define the variable name. You can just call the index of the list and perform all normal methods on that entry object. Something like `entrys[0].get()`. Also using exec and eval are almost never what you want to do here and is probably not very safe code wise. Instead I would keep it simple and just apply the entry directly to the list and call list[index] with whatever method you need.